# Do Claymore manga and anime have different endings?

Tags: claymore

I am reading the Claymore manga. There are around 5 chapters left before I finish it. In chapter 150 of the manga, I see that Teresa is alive, but I am pretty sure that in the anime, she was killed by Priscilla, and Priscilla was defeated by Clare at the end of the anime.

The difference in the endings of the storylines of the manga and the anime has confused me. Can you tell me what's going on here? Or does this simply mean that the anime's storyline is different from that of the manga?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** although strictly not spoiler info (they're all details that were mentioned before), reading the answers kind of spoils the excitement and all the built-ups that lead to the grand conclusion. I advise you to just continue reading chapter 151, which would clear your confusion.

---

The Claymore anime storyline is indeed different from that in the Claymore manga, albeit only substantially different for the ending. As the manga was still ongoing, the anime had to end at the conclusion of the Northern Campaign arc, but they somehow made the ending different.

Before the final chapters in the manga, Priscilla remained undefeated since she slew Teresa. What's more, she never met Clare and her comrades in the Northern Campaign arc, and would not have been defeated by Clare were she to meet her at that time. This was different in the anime, as you said, Priscilla was defeated by Clare, and seemingly more by her desire for revenge than by Teresa's flesh and soul, and therefore talent and power, that resided within Clare.

Teresa was killed for sure, in both the anime and the manga, but she still lived within Clare because Clare took up her flesh and blood (from her severed head) to become an unusual Claymore who is 1/4 yoma and 3/4 human. The Teresa that appears in chapter 150 is Clare's awakened form.

Comment: It's not quite Clare's awakened form.  She learns that one Claymore can awaken and stabilize another one with sufficient bonding between them, and finally realizes she can apply that knowledge to awaken not herself but Teresa.  Just preceding her transformation into Teresa we see her undergo this very realization, as she ponders what was meant when she was told that she was "awakening wrong".

Comment: @zibadawatimmy That is a great comment (should be an answer)! I missed all the subtleties when reading the manga. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Gao The full question was about the differences between the endings of the anime and the manga (and implicitly about why a difference existed), which your answer addressed.  The awakening bit was ancillary, and it was all I was up to addressing at the time (the mere last sentence of your answer, in fact).  You're welcome to edit your answer to include my comment, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Manga and Animations do have totally different endings. Anime has a rushed ending but completes the series, whereas Manga has a smooth ending yet leaves a bit incompletion or does not satify the feels of ending! Although, its just endings, but the whole story differs due to those changes. Personally, I liked the Manga more.